# Function definition and its forward declaration(s) in C

Tags: c, forward-declaration

I'm currently implementing a front-end of a C-based language. I'm confused how the modifiers and attributes (e.g. `__attribute__((some_attribute))`) of a forward declaration of a function and a function definition are handled. I cannot find any relevant information in the C standard, GNU documentation, or in the Internet. I will appreciate any kind of related books, links, etc.

How should I check whether the definition modifiers do not collide with the declaration? For example:

```
int foo(int);
static int foo(int a) { return a; }
```

will result in:

```
error: static declaration of ‘foo’ follows non-static declaration
```

whereas the following code is fine:

```
static int foo(int);
int foo(int a) { return a; }
```

I guess I can assume that all modifiers and attributes from the declaration are inherited by the definition. But when can the definition use modifiers and attributes that are not present in the declaration?

And what happens if there are more than one declaration precede definition?
What with a declaration which follows the definition?

Thanks in advance,

Grzegorz

Comment: Attributes are not *standard* C99, but a useful GCC extension.

Comment: "I cannot find any relevant information either in the C standard" - no wonder, they're not standard. The other rules are basically that modifiers and qualifiers should match exactly (apart from a few exceptions).

Comment: Thanks, but if we consider only the modifiers, where can I find any information how to handle the exceptions?
I know that attributes are not a standard, but still, how to handle attributes in a forward declaration and a definition? I was not able to find any information in GNU extensions documentation either.

Comment: In C, once you've declared something with a given linkage (`extern` or `static`), the linkage is cast in stone and you cannot change it. In particular, all further re-declarations as well as the definition are not allowed to explicitly specify another linkage, contradicting the first declaration. Here, `int foo(int);` is the 1st declaration of a (by default) `extern` function, which your `static` definition explicitly contradicts, whereas the 1st declaration `static int foo(int);` is followed by a definition with no linkage specifiers and which therefore does not contradict the declaration.

Comment: The symbol table and relocation tables, produced by the compiler, contain all the needed information that you are looking for.